# pyrogram why phone_number is "*********"?

Tags: get, chat, member, pyrogram

get_chat_members(pyrogram) gives characters ********* instead of phone_numbers

```
"_": "User",
"id": ##########,
"is_self": true,
"is_contact": false,
"is_mutual_contact": false,
"is_deleted": false,
"is_bot": false,
"is_verified": false,
"is_restricted": false,
"is_scam": false,
"is_fake": false,
"is_support": false,
"is_premium": false,
"first_name": "#########",
"last_name": "###########",
"status": "UserStatus.OFFLINE",
"last_online_date": "2023-01-13 16:18:34",
"username": "###########",
"phone_number": "*********"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `phone_number` field will be censored to protect the privacy, should the User object be printed or returned. If you want the actual number, access the value itself.

```py
user = app.get_users(789456123)
print(user)
{
    "_": "User",
    "id": 789456123,
    "phone_number": *********,
    ...
}
print(user.phone_number)
"49123456789"
```